# How to iterate through non-zeros values of an image ? - Python

Tags: python, image, loops

I have fond online a function to extract and display the dominant colors of an image. To save time, I want to iterate only on the non-zeros pixels instead of the whole image. However the way I changed the function raises an error :

```
   if row != [0,0,0]:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Here is the modified code :

```
def dominantColor(image) :
    from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, show
    from scipy.cluster.vq import whiten
    from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans
    import pandas as pd

r = []
g = []
b = []
for row in image :
    if row != [0,0,0]: #the part I added to the original code
        print(row)
        for temp_r, temp_g, temp_b in row:
            r.append(temp_r)
            g.append(temp_g)
            b.append(temp_b)

image_df = pd.DataFrame({'red': r, 'green': g, 'blue': b})
image_df['scaled_color_red'] = whiten(image_df['red'])
image_df['scaled_color_blue'] = whiten(image_df['blue'])
image_df['scaled_color_green'] = whiten(image_df['green'])

cluster_centers, _ = kmeans(image_df[['scaled_color_red','scaled_color_blue','scaled_color_green']], 3)
dominant_colors = []
red_std, green_std, blue_std = image_df[['red','green','blue']].std()
for cluster_center in cluster_centers:
    red_scaled, green_scaled, blue_scaled = cluster_center
    dominant_colors.append((
        red_scaled * red_std / 255,
        green_scaled * green_std / 255,
        blue_scaled * blue_std / 255
    ))
imshow([dominant_colors])
show()

return dominant_colors
```

How should I correct my iteration loop to remove the error and have only the non-zeros values of my image ? (NB : the image is actually `mask * original_image`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `.all()` method after that comparison if you want co compare arrays element wise. So `if (row == [0,0,0]).all()`.

```
import numpy as np

image = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
])

for row in image:
    if not (row == [0, 0, 0]).all():
        print(row)
```

Result:

```
[1 0 0]
[0 0 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I tried both .all() and .any() method copy pasting your syntax, however it seems the zero values are still taken into account. The `print(row)` line I added right after the `if` loop prints stuff like this :
 `[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]`
while the code is running. How is that possible ?...

Comment: `if (row == [0,0,0]).all()` what is that supposed to mean? are you call `all` on a `bool`?

Comment: Not a bool, but array of booleans. `print(np.array([0, 0, 1]) == [0, 0, 0])` => `[ True  True False]`.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I don't get why I still have `[[0 0 0]  [0 0 0]  [0 0 0]  ...  [0 0 0]  [0 0 0]  [0 0 0]]` and only zeros printed in my terminal but I guess it works anyway and is faster ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, the answer is in the error log that you posted:

> `if row != [0,0,0]:`
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

So, the `any` function check if any of the elements in the row are evaluated as true:

```
for row in image :
    if any(row): #enter the if block if any element is not 0
        print(row)
        for temp_r, temp_g, temp_b in row:
            r.append(temp_r)
            g.append(temp_g)
            b.append(temp_b)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Is it normal that after correcting as you suggested, I still have arrays of 0 printed in my terminal ? should'nt they be ignored if the zeros values led to not entering the ìf` loop ?

Comment: I did an edit, can you try now?